# Oracle APEX Partial Page Refresh Reporting

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report with a separate filter on top of the page. When I enter custom dates into the filter it refreshes the report to show the correct data within the data range. Then when I go to the download report function as CSV - the CSV contains way more data then it should and what is shown on the actual interactive report.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if filter was ignored.

Check filter items and see what is their **source** set to; I guess that now it is "Always, replacing any existing value in session state" - set it to "Only when current value in session state is null". Then download data and see what happens.